# Is there a way to implement action function in pandas series using boolean funtion?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, conditional-statements

I am trying to implement action function for stock market close price..the logic is

```
Action [ i ] = 1 if Close[ i+1 ] > Close[ i ]
Action [ i ] = (-1) if Close[ i+1 ] < Close[ i ]
```

This needs to be implemented for a dataframe which has Adjusted Close price.

the dataframe looks like this

```
Adj Close
1144.973755
1133.032471
1130.913696
1133.176880
1135.295532
1127.495117
```

I expect the output in a new dataframe Action, with output

```
1 if df['Adj close'][0] < df['Adj Close'][1]
-1 if df['Adj close'][0] > df['Adj Close'][1]

Adj Close   Action
1144.973755  1
1133.032471 -1
1130.913696 -1
1133.176880  1
1135.295532  1
1127.495117 -1
```

How shall i write a conditional statement if i want to implement this function?

Comment: What is expected output column?

Comment: @jezrael i edited the question to answer your question

Comment: And what about the case where there is no change in the price?

Answer (score 2):

Compare [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html)ed values with original and set new values by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['Action'] = np.where(df['Adj Close'].shift() > df['Adj Close'], -1, 1)
print (df)
     Adj Close  Action
0  1144.973755       1
1  1133.032471      -1
2  1130.913696      -1
3  1133.176880       1
4  1135.295532       1
5  1127.495117      -1
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['Adj Close'].shift())
0            NaN
1    1144.973755
2    1133.032471
3    1130.913696
4    1133.176880
5    1135.295532
Name: Adj Close, dtype: float64

print (df['Adj Close'].shift() > df['Adj Close'])
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
Name: Adj Close, dtype: bool
```

Custom function:

```
def action(df):
    df['Action'] = np.where(df['Adj Close'].shift() > df['Adj Close'], -1, 1)
    return df
print (action(df))
     Adj Close  Action
0  1144.973755       1
1  1133.032471      -1
2  1130.913696      -1
3  1133.176880       1
4  1135.295532       1
5  1127.495117      -1
```

First value is compared with nothing, so output is missing value if use `diff` function. If need custom value here is another solution with [`Series.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html):

```
diff = df['Adj Close'].diff()
df['Action'] = np.select([diff.isna(), diff > 0], [0, 1], -1)
```

Or:

```
shifted = df['Adj Close'].shift()
df['Action'] = np.select([shifted > df['Adj Close'], shifted < df['Adj Close']], [-1, 1], 0)

print (df)
     Adj Close  Action
0  1144.973755       0
1  1133.032471      -1
2  1130.913696      -1
3  1133.176880       1
4  1135.295532       1
5  1127.495117      -1
```

Solution above is from expected output, it seems if need solution by formula:

```
df['Action'] = np.where(df['Adj Close'].shift(-1) > df['Adj Close'], 1, -1)
print (df)
     Adj Close  Action
0  1144.973755      -1
1  1133.032471      -1
2  1130.913696       1
3  1133.176880       1
4  1135.295532      -1
5  1127.495117      -1
```

Comment: can we define a function to write the same operation?

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Action'] = np.where(df['Adj Close'].diff()>0, 1,-1)
```

Or np.select if special action when diff = 0